# How to add an Array to an AVERAGEIF(S) formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm an absolute novice and have created a Google Sheets for cooking recipes and am trying to create arrays so every time I add a recipe form a new book/chef/country, their score automatically updates.

Arrays are working fine for all formulas except AVERAGEIF and AVERAGEIFS.

This is the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3bpNFy9k1h8anZJfefk6KrGYSy7mW2izxKQZb9mWoU/edit?usp=sharing

The particular problem points are in the hidden tabs (Book Rating, Chef Rating, Country Rating) in Columns F, H and I.

Comment: Did you fix this? Please try to keep your questions more focussed - see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<3, "-", IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(
 {'Form Responses 1'!C:C,'Form Responses 1'!L:L}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This has worked for those columns - thanks @player0. How do I use the same logic to add an array to an AVERAGIFS which includes a wildcard search? (Columns H and I)

Comment: Thanks @player0. I'm almost there I think - much appreciated. The only issue - when I apply this to the Country Rating tab, I can't get it to pick up those with a Veg/Vegan count of 3 or more.